# Htaccess rewrite rules for pagination

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

What can be problem with this rules?
If i open page without pagination all is working fine

```
RewriteRule ^videos/tagged/([A-Za-z0-9-\s]+)/$ index.php?mode=tags&type=videos&keyword=$1 [L]
```

But with pagination does not work, back me 404 error when i click to page2.html, query is working fine, i can access page without this rewriterule

```
RewriteRule ^videos/tagged/([A-Za-z0-9-\s]+)/page(.*).html$ index.php?mode=tags&type=videos&keyword=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

Comment: What is the link for page 2?

Comment: http:/example.com/videos/tagged/tag-name/page2.html

Comment: So `index.php?mode=tags&type=videos&keyword=tag-name&page=2` loads fine? You should escape the `.` and use a number `\d` after the `page`  probably not your issues though. Do you have other rules in place before this?

Comment: Hmm i have, looks that this line is problem
RewriteRule ^videos/(.*)/(.*).html$ video.php?id=$1 [QSA]
This line is loaded before

Comment: Looks like there might be issue with the sequence in which htaccess rules are written. Can you please share your htaccess file content.

Comment: Problem was in line above, when i add RewriteRule ^videos/tagged/... before RewriteRule ^videos/(.*)/(.*)... all is working fine, not sure is this correct way but for now all is working as expected

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^videos/tagged/([A-Za-z0-9-\s]+)/page([0-9]+).html$ index.php?mode=tags&type=videos&keyword=$1&page=$2 [L]
```